# Android: How to refresh CursorAdapter with support for older APIs?

Tags: android, android-cursoradapter

I read some posts and found that `reQuery()` is deprecated and some suggested using `SwapCursor()` or `ChangeCursor()`.

I have a Favorite button on whose click I update DB and change color of the Button. When I scroll and come back to particular view(and Button) color is reset. 
I know it is because view is recycled. I have a condition based on a DB column value to set the color of the Button.

I want view to get updated values from DB after I press the Button. For which I have to refresh/requery Cursor/DB.

How do I do that with CursorAdapter keeping in mind that my min. API is 19?

**UPDATE**
CursorAdapter code:

public class ToDoCursorAdapter extends CursorAdapter {

```
SparseBooleanArray selectionArrayAr = new SparseBooleanArray();
SparseBooleanArray selectionArrayRef = new SparseBooleanArray();
SparseBooleanArray selectionArrayFav = new SparseBooleanArray();
//Boolean isSet = false;
private MainButtons_Interface mAdapterCallback;


public ToDoCursorAdapter(Context context, Cursor cursor) {
    super(context, cursor, 0);
}

@Override
public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {

    ViewHolderItem viewHolder = new ViewHolderItem();
    View rowView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.listview, parent, false);

    viewHolder.engTextV = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.engText);

    viewHolder.arTextV = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.arabText);
    viewHolder.buttonIAV = (Button) rowView.findViewById(R.id.buttonIA); //For Arabic Text


    viewHolder.refTextV = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.refText);
    viewHolder.buttonIRV = (Button) rowView.findViewById(R.id.buttonIR); //For Ref Text

    viewHolder.buttonIFV = (ImageButton) rowView.findViewById(R.id.buttonF);


    rowView.setTag(viewHolder);
    return rowView;
}

@Override
public void bindView(final View view, final Context context, final Cursor cursor) {


    final ViewHolderItem viewHolder = (ViewHolderItem) view.getTag();

    String arabic = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("PlainArab_Text")).trim().replaceAll("[\n]{2,}", "TWOFEEDS").replaceAll("\n", " ").replaceAll(" +", " ").replaceAll("<br/>", "\n").replaceAll("TWOFEEDS", "\n")  + "\n";
    String english = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("PlainEng_Text")).trim().replaceAll("[\n]{2,}", "TWOFEEDS").replaceAll("\n", " ").replaceAll(" +", " ").replaceAll("<br/>", "\n").replaceAll("TWOFEEDS", "\n")  + "\n";
    String ref = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("REF")).trim().replaceAll("<br/>    <br/>", " ").replaceAll("<br/>", "\n");

    final Integer HadithID = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("ID"));
    final Integer IsFav =  cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("IsFavorite"));

    viewHolder.arTextV.setText(arabic);
    viewHolder.engTextV.setText(english);
    viewHolder.refTextV.setText(ref);

    final int position = cursor.getPosition();

    boolean isSelectedA = selectionArrayAr.get(position);
    boolean isSelectedR = selectionArrayRef.get(position);
    boolean isSelectedF = selectionArrayFav.get(position);

    if (isSelectedA) {
        viewHolder.arTextV.setVisibility(view.GONE);
        viewHolder.buttonIAV.setText("Show Arabic Version");
    } else if (!isSelectedA){
        viewHolder.arTextV.setVisibility(view.VISIBLE);
        viewHolder.buttonIAV.setText("Hide Arabic Version");
    }

    if (isSelectedR) {
        viewHolder.refTextV.setVisibility(view.GONE);
        viewHolder.buttonIRV.setText("Show Refrence");
    } else if (!isSelectedR){
        viewHolder.refTextV.setVisibility(view.VISIBLE);
        viewHolder.buttonIRV.setText("Hide Refrence");
    }

    //boolean isSelectedF = selectionArrayFav.get(position);
    if(isSelectedF) {
        viewHolder.buttonIFV.setImageResource(R.drawable.favoritebutton_afterclick);
    } else if (!isSelectedF){
        viewHolder.buttonIFV.setImageResource(R.drawable.favoritebutton);
    }


    //Arabic Button
    viewHolder.buttonIAV.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener()
                    { @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                        boolean isSelectedAc = selectionArrayAr.get(position);
                            if(!isSelectedAc) {
                                viewHolder.arTextV.setVisibility(v.GONE);
                                viewHolder.buttonIAV.setText("Show Arabic Version");
                                setSelectedAr(position, true);
                            } else if (isSelectedAc){
                                viewHolder.arTextV.setVisibility(v.VISIBLE);
                                setSelectedAr(position, false);
                                viewHolder.buttonIAV.setText("Hide Arabic version");
                            }
                        }
                    }
    );

    //Ref Button
   viewHolder.buttonIRV.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener()
            { @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                boolean isSelectedRc = selectionArrayRef.get(position);
                if(!isSelectedRc) {
                    viewHolder.refTextV.setVisibility(v.GONE);
                    viewHolder.buttonIRV.setText("Show Reference");
                    setSelectedRef(position, true);
                } else if (isSelectedRc){
                    viewHolder.refTextV.setVisibility(v.VISIBLE);
                    setSelectedRef(position, false);
                    viewHolder.buttonIRV.setText("Hide Reference");
                }
            }
            }
    );


    //Fav Button
    viewHolder.buttonIFV.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener()
            { @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                boolean isSelectedF = selectionArrayFav.get(position);
                boolean IsSet = ((ListViewActivity) context).addRemFav(HadithID);
                String mess ="";

                if(IsSet){
                    mess = "Hadith add to Favorite list";
                } else if(!IsSet){
                    mess = "Hadith removed from Favorite list";
                }

                if(!isSelectedF) {
                    viewHolder.buttonIFV.setImageResource(R.drawable.favoritebutton_afterclick);
                    setSelectedF(position, true);

                } else if (isSelectedF){
                    viewHolder.buttonIFV.setImageResource(R.drawable.favoritebutton);
                    setSelectedF(position, false);
                }

                Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), mess, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            }
    );
}


// our ViewHolder.
static class ViewHolderItem {
    TextView engTextV;
    TextView arTextV;
    TextView refTextV;

    Button buttonIAV;
    Button buttonIRV;
    ImageButton buttonIFV;
}

// Method to mark items in selection
public void setSelectedAr(int position, boolean isSelected) {
    selectionArrayAr.put(position, isSelected);
}

public void setSelectedRef(int position, boolean isSelected) {
    selectionArrayRef.put(position, isSelected);
}
public void setSelectedF(int position, boolean isSelected) {
    selectionArrayFav.put(position, isSelected);
}
```

**UPDATE**

I added this logic to my function which was called on clicking the Button.

```
 Cursor todoCursor1 = hadDB.rawQuery("SELECT  ID as _id, * FROM HAD_TABLE WHERE ID < 7001 ", null);
        todoAdapter.changeCursor(todoCursor1);
```

Basically, you just need to requery DB so that you get updated records/Data and then change your current cursor with new one, todoCursor1 is my case above.

Also, `changeCursor()` will close your current cursor, in case you would want to go back to old cursor you should use `swapCursor()` instead as it will return you old cursor.

Now my only thing I want to know is, if this will work for APIs 19 and up.

Comment: Could you post adapter's code? It would be far easier to correct it directly

Comment: @fillobotto Posted the code.

Comment: why dont you use `SimpleCursorAdapter`?

Comment: This is my first app. I needed to use `ListView` because at the end of my previous efforts on this app I found out `WebView` was slow to display 7k DB records. The I just started with `ListView` and `CursorAdapter` seemed simpler : )

I just want to finish this app. I have been working on it for a month now. Learned many things. 

Don't want change code again : )

Comment: so if `CursorAdapter` seemed simpler then `SimpleCursorAdapter` would be even more  hmmm, simple...

Comment: @pskink may be in next app.

Comment: @pskink 
Is there any way we can chat? I don't find chat option on your profile.

Comment: i have no idea if that works: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154416/how-to-refresh-cursoradapter-with-support-for-older-apis but you can try...

Answer (score 0):

I added this logic to my function which was called on clicking the Button.

```
 Cursor todoCursor1 = hadDB.rawQuery("SELECT  ID as _id, * FROM HAD_TABLE WHERE ID < 7001 ", null);
        todoAdapter.changeCursor(todoCursor1);
```

Basically, you just need to requery DB so that you get updated records/Data and then change your current cursor with new one, todoCursor1 is my case above.

Also, `changeCursor()` will close your current cursor, in case you would want to go back to old cursor you should use `swapCursor()` instead as it will return you old cursor.